# How do you sum a range of rounded values in Excel

Tags: excel, sum, rounding

I want to sum the following integers but only their rounded down values.

```
    A     B
    3     2
    2     3
    4.5   8
    4.5   4
    5     7
    6.5   10
    1     2
```

I was expecting something like `=sum(rounddown(A1:A7,0)` to be applicable here but rounddown won't handle ranges.

**Edit:** I'd just like to amend this question to ask how I would do this if the range was part of a sumif formula.

example: `=sumif(B1:B7 ">5", A1:A7)`

I've tried `{=sumif(B1:B7 ">5", rounddown(A1:A7,0))}` with ctrl-shift-enter but get an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUM(ROUNDDOWN(A1:A7,0))
```

Entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> so that it's treated as an *array formula*. You'll see that's worked as the formula will be displayed in the formula bar in curly braces: `{=SUM(ROUNDDOWN(A1:A7,0))}`

**EDIT:**

Another approach for your supplementary question, again using an array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(B1:B7>5,ROUNDDOWN(A1:A7,0)))
```

Again, entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: I've added a follow-up question if you're able to help.

Comment: I've edited my answer to offer an alternative, array formula answer for your 'sumif' question.

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
'sum of rounddown
=SUMPRODUCT(ROUNDDOWN(A1:A7, 0))
'sum of rounddown (conditional)
=SUMPRODUCT(ROUNDDOWN(A1:A7, 0)*(B1:B7>5))
```

[image]